# Is the journal indexing by SCOPUS meaningless?

Tags: publications, peer-review, journals, paper-submission

A journal that I want to submit my manuscript is SCOPUS and WoS indexed (Q3, impact factor: 1.89, SJR 0.264, Fee: around 1000$). But my Professor said SCOPUS indexed journals are MEANINGLESS!(two months ago he said SCOPUS indexed journals are also OKAY).

He prefers SCI-indexed journal which is Q3, impact factor:0.7, SJR:0.224, Fee: around 250-300$. I understand, maybe SCI index is a little bit higher than SCOPUS but if you scale SCOPUS(IF:1.89) and SCI(IF:0.7).

Which one is better to publish in?

Comment: Indexing is a very weak indicator of quality.  A journal that is not indexed is probably bad, but otherwise you cannot draw any conclusions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scopus is quality-curated, i.e. getting indexed by it is not meaningless.

However, it is not as selective as the Science Citation Index, which remains the gold standard.

Therefore you are better off publishing in a SCI-indexed journal if you can. Arguing with your professor is unlikely to be a good idea in any case - they have much more experience than you and will have a better idea where to send your manuscript.